# Android - how do you manage multiple layout files in line with DRY principle?

Tags: android, layout

To support different resolutions, we need to make variations of layout files as described in [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) very well. Assuming you don't plan to show different arrangement of your UI but just want to stretch appropriately, your variations would be mostly about different weights. At least that is the case with my app so far.

Now, how do you manage changing the application with this structure? Since it repeats the layout many times, one layout change in your application causes multiple files change.

I thought of two options:

1. Changing the values dynamically in your code

   - Downside is your layout related work is spilled over to the code. I really don't like this.
2. Making child layout to extract common layout elements

   - Downside is your layout's hierarchy will be deeper and cluttered so it would be harder to figure out what's going on. Still, this is better than option #1 thanks to [Hierarchy Viewer](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-ui.html). I am not sure if this approach will be always achievable.

If you could share your tricks to get through this, it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found a solution. I will accept it as an answer if others give thumbs up.

I found Configuration qualifiers described in [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) works not only for `res/drawable` and `res/layout` but also for `res/values`. So on my `layout/some_layout.xml`, I say like this:

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imagePlay"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/button_size"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/button_size"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:src="@drawable/play" />
```

Then on `values/layout.xml` file you define the default `button_size`:

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="button_size">44dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

And on `values-xlarge/layout.xml` file you define the xlarge mode `button_size`:

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="button_size">66dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

I didn't try other `values` resources, but I assume it also works for [Styles and Themes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html) so in case your layout customization is a little bit more than a size or weight, you could define a style in the values and use it.

Comment: I think this solution looks complicated over an application with many layouts. For each value in a layout, you have to specify a "variable" which seems quite confusing when it comes for debugging. However, lets hear what others think about!

Comment: @antoniom You are right to call this "variable". I wonder if your concern can be mitigated by proper naming practice. You could have one values xml file to keep common elements like button size, and then one values xml file per each layout files, and have the values xml filename to be `values\layout_*.xml`. Value names are better to start with `layout_*`, since `R` doesn't give you a way to go by filename. You don't have to define everything as variable so I expect these `layout_*.xml` files are small. Did I miss a scenario that you specifically had in mind?

Comment: This is working well for me. Accepting this as answer - hopefully it will help others in the future, or somebody else will note better way to do it.

Comment: Really happy I stumbled on this solution. It adds a little indirection, but where possible, I'd rather have indirection than duplicate layout code!